# xlwt.Style.EasyXFCallerError while writing an Excel file using Python

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, xlwt

I was trying to write an Excel Sheet using python and encountered the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create_excel.py", line 29, in <module>
    ws.row(8).write(0,'',Style.easyxf('pattern: pattern solid, fore_colourgreen;'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwt/Style.py", line 618, in easyxf
    field_sep=field_sep, line_sep=line_sep, intro_sep=intro_sep, esc_char=esc_char, debug=debug)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwt/Style.py", line 574, in _parse_strg_to_obj
    raise EasyXFCallerError("no value supplied for %s.%s" % (section, k))
xlwt.Style.EasyXFCallerError: no value supplied for pattern.fore_colourgreen
```

The line that caused the above error is :-

```
ws.row(8).write(0,'',Style.easyxf('pattern: pattern solid, fore_colourgreen;'))
```

I also modified the line to:

```
ws.row(8).write(0,'',Style.easyxf('pattern: pattern solid, fore-colourgreen;'))
```

as some of the forums had `-` instead of `_` in `fore-colourgreen` but to no avail.

Can someone let me know whats the issue here?

Comment: I think it's just telling you that `pattern.fore_colourgreen` is undefined. I doubt the identifier would have a `-` because that would not be a legal Python identifier name. A search though the `xlwt` module's code did not turn up any predefine Patterns of that name or similar to it, so it looks like you'll have to define it yourself or use something else.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a space:

`'pattern: pattern solid, fore_colourgreen;'`

should be

`'pattern: pattern solid, fore_colour green;'`

It doesn't matter if you use a hyphen or underscore; `easyxf` handles either (by converting hyphens to underscores automatically).